# Forms Authentication - token send to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

When I send this token to Controller in WebApi I get information 401 (Unauthorized) Why? I take this token form login and it`s correct.

```
$scope.expiresCookie = $cookies.get('expires');
$scope.issuedCookie = $cookies.get('issued');
$scope.access_tokenCookie = $cookies.get('access_token');
$scope.expires_inCookie = $cookies.get('expires_in');
$scope.token_typeCookie = $cookies.get('token_type');
$scope.user_nameCookie = $cookies.get('user_name');


$scope.addLink = "http://localhost:56305/api/ProductInsuranceCar";


$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: $scope.addLink,
    headers: { 'Authorization': '' + $scope.token_typeCookie + ' ' + $scope.access_tokenCookie + '' },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.test = response;
}, function myError(response) {
});
```

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

Example correct request

[image]

When I use Advanced Rest Client I get information but in my method :/ not working...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be when calling web api from a different UI domain.

Cookies are not sent if domains are different. So, If you call from `localhost:64757` to `localhost:56305` cookies are not sent, that's why you are receiving Unathorized 401 error.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer. Position of header is important :/

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
headers: { 'Authorization': $scope.Authorization2 }
```